# Converting writer to string when printing out template

Tags: java

For creating this output I have used https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java

```
{{#items}}
Name: {{name}}
Price: {{price}}
  {{#features}}
  Feature: {{description}}
  {{/features}}
{{/items}}
```

another part

```
import com.github.mustachejava.DefaultMustacheFactory;
import com.github.mustachejava.Mustache;
import com.github.mustachejava.MustacheFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Example {

    List<Item> items() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Item("Item 1", "$19.99", Arrays.asList(new Feature("New!"), new Feature("Awesome!"))));
    }

    static class Item {
        Item(String name, String price, List<Feature> features) {
            this.name = name;
            this.price = price;
            this.features = features;
        }

        String name, price;
        List<Feature> features;
    }

    static class Feature {
        Feature(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        String description;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        MustacheFactory mf = new DefaultMustacheFactory();
        Mustache mustache = mf.compile("template.mustache");
        mustache.execute(new PrintWriter(System.out), new Example()).flush();
    }
}
```

Can someone explaine if I can someone get this output in String? If yes, how? I have already tried searching on stack and I haven't found anything like this. It's not duplicate.

First part is my template.mustache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [StringWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html):

```
StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
mustache.execute(out, new Example()).flush();
String str = out.toString();
```

(Note: I am not sure how Mustache works, so only look at the use of StringWriter!)